# Cygwin - Obtaining new commands

Tags: ubuntu, windows, cygwin

I installed Cygwin to get the bash shell on window 8, and I'm not able to use `vim`, `ssh`, `apt`, `install` command. Many commands work now, while it didn't work in few minutes ago. What could I do to obtain those new command with Cygwin?

**EDIT :**

I know now I have to install `apt-cyg` using this [website](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg). This is exactly what I did, but even if the "apt-cyg file" is in the `Downloads` directory, I still don't know how to use this file to make it work. Could anyone be able to tell me what are the following steps?

Comment: are you familiar with using a shell? I.e. are you otherwise familiar with using  Bash, or any other shell? Also, are you familiar with using package managers? Are you also aware about internal and external commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows MSI installation package for Cygwin at www.cygwin.com includes almost all these commands as part of the standard recommended installation. It certainly includes `vim`, `ssh` and `install`. (The ones it doesn't include are the `apt-*` family, which is what you're trying to add with this third-party tool.)

The installation instructions you've cited give very a straightforward recipe for getting it to work:

> `apt-cyg` is a simple script. To install:
>
> ```
> lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg
> install apt-cyg /bin
> ```
>
> Example use of `apt-cyg`:
>
> ```
> apt-cyg install nano
> ```